# SEAM FacesMessage not showing

Tags: java, seam

I'm trying to add an information message to the user on an existing large SEAM project. I've added the `<h:messages/>` to the .xhtml page and these are my attempts in the code of a class called `AbstractChartController` but when the page refreshes after the action, non of the FacesMessages are displayed, anybody know what I can try next?

```
if (axis.getAxisType() == AxisType.LOGARITHMIC  && axis.getLowestValue() <= 0d){
    //Non of this code works:
    //Attempt 1
    FacesMessages facesMessages = FacesMessages.instance();
    facesMessages.add(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Note: Data contains values below or equal to zero so cannot be plotted on a logarithmic axis.");
    //Attempt 2
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Test2");
    context.addMessage(null, message);
    //Attempt 3
    org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesContext myContext = (org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesContext) Component.getInstance("FacesContext");
    if (myContext != null) { //Why is this null in debug?
        myContext.getContext().addMessage("Test3", message);
    }
    //Attempt 4:
    //StatusMessages.instance()
    //.add(StatusMessage.Severity.INFO, "Test4");
    // (Compile time error above that it can't find StatusMessages class to import)
    System.out.println("FacesMessage added");
    ...
```

Edit: The "Faces Message added" is displaying in my eclipse console so code is being run

I'm thinking this class can't access the FacesContext for some reason? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

```
StatusMessages statusMessages =  Component.getInstance("statusMessages");
statusMessages.add(Severity.ERROR,"Note: Data contains values below or equal to zero so cannot be plotted on a logarithmic axis.");
```

Comment: FacesMessages facesMessages =  Component.getInstance("facesMessages");
facesMessages.add(Severity.ERROR,"Note: Data contains values below or equal to zero so cannot be plotted on a logarithmic axis.");

Comment: Should work aswell but statusmessage should be the way togo if you can't find that class you probably not have the right jar, what jboss,seam etc?

Comment: Since StatusMessages is in jboss-seam.jar you should look over your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately if I add jboss-seam.jar to my build path when eclipse prompts me to, the ant compile task I have to use with this project fails with "cannot find symbol class StatusMessage, location: package org.jboss.seam.international"

Comment: I havnt used ant that much i build mycket seam projekts with maven.  Howevere i think you need tog add the jar tog your ant buildpath as well not just i eclipse.